# How do I add boolean to form content C#

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am sending data to a site, but when I add `true` to the form content, it adds it as a `string`. How do I convert it to a `Boolean` type?

The result I want:

[image]

My actual result:

[image]

```cs
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
StringContent content = new StringContent("{\"password\":\"123123asd\"," + "\"remember_me\":\""+true+"\"," + "\"username\":\"" +"feridisgenderli"+ "\"}");
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync(LoginAPI.ToString(), content);
var stringContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.Write(stringContent);
```

Comment: Dont post images of code, post the code itself.

Comment: For preference, don't build your JSON by hand, then you won't have syntax issues. Much simpler, and more readable, and less error-prone, to build an object and then serialise it to JSON using an established code library which knows how to serialise properly (e.g. Newtonsoft.JSON or a similar one).

Comment: Something to keep in mind, passing credentials like that are really bad. I would contact the owners of this API.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifically wrapping it in quotes:

```
StringContent content = new StringContent("{\"password\":\"123123asd\"," + "\"remember_me\":\""+true+"\"," + "\"username\":\"" +"feridisgenderli"+ "\"}");
```

Dont do that and it wont have quotes:

```
StringContent content = new StringContent("{\"password\":\"123123asd\"," + "\"remember_me\":true," + "\"username\":\"" +"feridisgenderli"+ "\"}");
```

But more generally, you usually wouldn't build up JSON using a string. Use an object and serialize it to JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating a string, first of all. This happens to be okay in C# with boolean types, but not all languages will transform `true` into `"true"`. Consider [serializing an object instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0).

The c# code `"\"remember_me\":\""+true+"\","` will result in  `"remember_me": "true",` because you have included `\"` around your boolean value, i.e.:

```cs
Console.Write("\"" + true + "\""); // -> "true"
Console.Write("" + true); // -> true
```